# How to deploy camel-servlet as a OSGI in JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: servlets, osgi, apache-camel, jboss-eap-6

I'm starting to work with Apache Camel and I want to create an OSGI bundle for the camel-servlet component.

Looking the documentation on camel site, I found this tutorial, http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-osgi-camel-part1.html, but looks like it is deprecated. Looking for the documentation, I found that all camel components are OSGI compliance.

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.1 as my container server. I deployed the camel-servlet component, and went to the OSGI tab in the JBoss admin tool. A new service appear, called **org.apache.camel.camel-servlet**, version **2.10.0**. When I try to start the bundle, I have this message in the log:

```
15:45:58,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS011916: Activate deferred module phase for: org.apache.camel.camel-servlet:2.10.0
15:45:58,625 ERROR [org.jboss.as.osgi] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS011909: Management operation 'start' failed: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: JBOSGI011250: Cannot resolve bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-servlet:2.10.0
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.service.BundleLifecycleIntegration$BundleLifecycleImpl.activateDeferredPhase(BundleLifecycleIntegration.java:299)
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.service.BundleLifecycleIntegration$BundleLifecycleImpl.start(BundleLifecycleIntegration.java:229)
    at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.startWithOptions(AbstractBundleState.java:537)
    at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.start(AbstractBundleState.java:525)
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.management.BundleResourceHandler.handleOperation(BundleResourceHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.management.BundleResourceHandler.executeRuntimeStep(BundleResourceHandler.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractRuntimeOnlyHandler$1.execute(AbstractRuntimeOnlyHandler.java:90) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:440) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:322) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:229) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:224) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:194) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:115) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:398) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:388) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.processRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:320)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.doHandle(DomainApiHandler.java:226)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handle(DomainApiHandler.java:233)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handle(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:710)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.RealmReadinessFilter.doFilter(RealmReadinessFilter.java:47)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DmrFailureReadinessFilter.doFilter(DmrFailureReadinessFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.0.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve HostBundleRevision[org.apache.camel.camel-servlet:2.10.0]: missing requirement XPackageRequirement[atts={osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet, version=[2.5,3)},[org.apache.camel.camel-servlet:2.10.0]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populateResource(Candidates.java:285)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populate(Candidates.java:153)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.felix.StatelessResolver.resolve(StatelessResolver.java:56)
    at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverImpl.resolveAndApply(ResolverImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.service.BundleLifecycleIntegration$BundleLifecycleImpl.activateDeferredPhase(BundleLifecycleIntegration.java:296)
```

There is a bundle with the symbolic name **org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec with** that the location is **javax.servlet.api**.

I google how to deploy the camel-servlet as OSGI bundle but I did not find any clue.

Comment: OSGi can be really tricky to get working. On JBoss I suggest to use WAR/EAR or JBoss Modules. For OSGi you should take a look at Apache Karaf / ServiceMix. As that runs well with Camel. Any other OSGi combo is really hard to get working well.

Comment: Hi Claus, thanks for the answer. I put this questions to see if OSGI was a solution for this problem with SwitchYard: https://community.jboss.org/thread/232628
You and Keith has the same solution, maybe is the way to go ;)

Thank you!!